# Internet research tool allowing you to arrange notes on one page (mindmaps?)

Tags: webapp-rec

Does anyone know of any (preferably online) tools that allow you to create a visual scrap book of online research, with links to pages, snippets of text, and images?

Maybe something similar to [Notefish](http://www.notefish.com/)? (I couldn't work out any way to get images into the notes).

[Here](http://www.notefish.com/notes.php?p=1621.)'s an example page you're supposed to be able to achieve with Notefish.

Does anyone know of something similar to/better than Notefish?

Answer (score 0):

From [Digital Inspiration](http://www.labnol.org/internet/office/google-docs-guide-tutorial/4999/) the last question is:

> Q. Can I use Google Docs like Microsoft OneNote for taking notes and saving [web clippings](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/review-web-clipping-tools-save-webpages-images-internet-videos-permanently/2266/)?
>
> A: Open a new Google Document in a separate browser tab and drag the clipping from another browser tab / window into this document. That’s it. Not sure if this works with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com).

From their website:

> Put your thoughts, ideas, inspiration,
> and things to remember all in one
> place. Use Evernote for work, for
> play, and for everything that’s
> noteworthy. Here are a few
> suggestions:
>
> Snap a photo of a business card with
> your phone, and have an easy way to
> store and access contacts.
>
> Capture
> plane tickets and confirmation
> numbers, hotel invoices, and receipts
> for your expense reports.
>
> Get
> inspired. Keep a file of anything cool
> you want to buy for yourself or as a
> gift, whether it’s online or out in
> the real world.
>
> Keep notes from your
> meetings all in one place. Take a
> picture of a whiteboard and you’ll be
> able to find it later.
>
> Plan your next
> trip. Clip web pages, maps, and
> itineraries. Capture sights, sounds,
> tastes, and anything else. Research
> web sites and clip pages directly from
> your browser.
>
> Keep a record of your
> favorite wines by snapping a photo of
> the label when you find one you like.
>
> Remember the things you were supposed
> to remember. Create to-do lists, jot
> down random thoughts, leave a voice
> memo, and more.
>
> Create notes right
> from Twitter and save tweets that you
> like by following @myEN on Twitter.

Evernote is free (although there is a storage limit) I use it for note-taking and it works extremely well.

Comment: Evernote does seem like a great tool, but it just seems to be built for taking lots of separate notes/snippets. I need something that allows you to arrange things on one page so you can get an overview of your research and keep things together.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a Notefish replacement as well; something that will work in Chrome. The closest thing I've found so far is Corkboard ( http://corkboard.me/simple ). It's not as good as Notefish, but they are just starting out and open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How about [bubbl.us](https://bubbl.us/) or [mindmeister](http://www.mindmeister.com/)?
Or:

- [Mind42](http://mind42.com/)
- [Dabbleboard](http://www.dabbleboard.com/)
- [Mindomo](http://www.mindomo.com/)

Here is a bigger list: http://freenuts.com/top-10-free-online-mind-mapping-tools/

Comment: @Makyen yeah, that’s the reason I edited that answer. Thanks for the info!